# Delete BASH history on exit for all users

Tags: bash, rhel

Using Red Hat Enterprise Linux is it possible to place a global option that whenever a user exits an SSH connection the BASH history for that user is cleared?

Comment: There's not much you can do if the users have customized their `bash` session to save their history in an arbitrary file.

Comment: Try setting `/etc/bash.bash_logout` as I suggest in my answer.

Comment: None of the below suggested answers work.

Answer (score 1):

In the `/etc/bash.bash_logout` script you can put:

```
unset HISTFILE
```

The default for `HISTFILE` is `~/.bash_history`. The user can set this to whatever they wish. If it's not set, the logout process doesn't write the history information that's in RAM to the history file.

Comment: This would only clear the in-memory history, which doesn't persist after the shell exits anyway.

Comment: See my answer. There's no guarantee that `.bash_history` is used to store the history.

Comment: `bash` does not have a global logout file by default, although it appears you can enable it at compile time. I don't know if that is executed before or after `~/.bash_logout` where available.

Comment: @chepner I have a fairly "default" installation of Fedora 18 and `/etc/bash.bash_logout` is operational on my system. I didn't compile the system myself.

Comment: Looks like it's disabled in the `bash`s installed on my Mac OS X box, but is enabled on one of my Linux boxes at work. It also appears (which you have probably confirmed) that it is sourced after the user's logout file.

Comment: HOWEVER, :), the user could always make sure his history is written out before the global file unsets `HISTFILE`.

Comment: @chepner yep, I agree, the ultimate "cheat" would be that the user could run the `history` command into some arbitrary file then copy it back over after they login.

Answer (score 1):

Put the following in `~/.bash_logout`

```
echo > $HISTFILE
```

This will erase the saved history for a user at logout, but will keep a useful running history when user is logged-in.

Answer (score 0):

I know you can manually run

```
history -c
```

I think you can put this into your `~/.bash_logout`.

Answer (score 0):

The user can always save their history to a non-standard file and reload it on the next login, so their isn't much you can do from a global standpoint to stop it.

For example, Bob might put the following in his `~/.bash_login`:

```
HISTFILE=~/my_secret_history_file
```

Comment: Is it possible globally to set history to `/dev/null` or something?

Comment: No, because the user configuration files are sourced after the global ones. The best you can do is set a policy that history cannot be stored, but there's no technical way to enforce such a policy.

Answer (score 0):

When needed to let the histories empty - I use symlinking them to /dev/null...

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    9 Dez 16 19:10 .ash_history -> /dev/null
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    9 Dez 16 19:10 .bash_history -> /dev/null
```

...then the history of typed commands work only for current session.
Starting a new shell, starting a new empty temporary history.
Symlinking them for normal users to `/dev/null` have to be done by: `root`